# Calling a member function pointer stored in a std map

Tags: c++, stl, function-pointers

I'm storing a map in a class that has strings as keys and pointers to member functions as values. I'm having trouble calling the right function throw the function pointer. 
Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;


class Preprocessor;

typedef void (Preprocessor::*function)();



class Preprocessor
{

public:
    Preprocessor();
   ~Preprocessor();

   void processing(const string before_processing);

private:

   void   take_new_key();

   map<string, function>   srch_keys;

   string  after_processing;
};


Preprocessor::Preprocessor()
{
   srch_keys.insert(pair<string, function>(string("#define"), &Preprocessor::take_new_key));
}

Preprocessor::~Preprocessor()
{

}


void Preprocessor::processing(const string before_processing)
{
   map<string, function>::iterator result = srch_keys.find("#define");

   if(result != srch_keys.end())
      result->second; 
}


void Preprocessor::take_new_key()
{
   cout << "enters here";
}


int main()
{
   Preprocessor pre;
   pre.processing(string("...word #define other word"));

   return 0;
}
```

In function `Preprocessor::processing` if the string is found in the map then, I call the proper function. The problem is that, in this code, `Preprocessor::take_new_key` is never called.

Where is the mistake ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct syntax is this:

```
(this->*(result->second))();
```

That is ugly. So lets try this:

```
auto mem = result->second;  //C++11 only
(this->*mem)();
```

Use whichever makes you happy.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the syntax and I can't figure it out why can't I just write (*(result->second))();   Can you please provide me an answer for this ? Thanks

Comment: @Mike: To invoke a member function, you need an object. So why `(*(result->second))(); ` would work? Where is the object on which the member is invoked?

Answer (score 3):

`result->second` does not call the function pointer. Try `((*this).*result->second)();`