# How to fix error: assigning to 'mapped_type' (aka 'int (*)()') from incompatible type 'int (Rsh::*)(*)'?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, g++

I didn't understand why I have this error:

> error: assigning to 'mapped_type' (aka 'int (*)()') from incompatible type 'int (Rsh::*)(*)'

All lib needed is already included in another `.h`

I have an `Rsh.h` with:

```
class Rsh
{
    private:
        map<string, int(*)(const string &, FILE*)>  supportedCmds;

    public:
                            Rsh                     ();
                            ~Rsh                    ();
        void                setup                   ();
};
```

And a Rsh.cpp with :

```
void                Rsh::setup()
{
    // Fill up list of supported commands
    supportedCmds["cd"]         = &Rsh::ashCd;
    supportedCmds["ls"]         = &Rsh::ashLs;
    supportedCmds["pwd"]        = &Rsh::ashPwd;
    supportedCmds["history"]    = &Rsh::ashHistory;
    supportedCmds["exit"]       = NULL;
}
```

And the output g++ message is this :

```
src/Rsh.cpp:24:26: error: assigning to 'mapped_type' (aka 'int (*)(const
      std::__1::basic_string<char> &, __sFILE *)') from incompatible type 'int (Rsh::*)(const
      string &, FILE *)'
        supportedCmds["cd"]                     = &Rsh::ashCd;
                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~
src/Rsh.cpp:25:26: error: assigning to 'mapped_type' (aka 'int (*)(const
      std::__1::basic_string<char> &, __sFILE *)') from incompatible type 'int (Rsh::*)(const
      string &, FILE *)'
        supportedCmds["ls"]                     = &Rsh::ashLs;
                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~
src/Rsh.cpp:26:26: error: assigning to 'mapped_type' (aka 'int (*)(const
      std::__1::basic_string<char> &, __sFILE *)') from incompatible type 'int (Rsh::*)(const
      string &, FILE *)'
        supportedCmds["pwd"]            = &Rsh::ashPwd;
                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
src/Rsh.cpp:27:29: error: assigning to 'mapped_type' (aka 'int (*)(const
      std::__1::basic_string<char> &, __sFILE *)') from incompatible type 'int (Rsh::*)(const
      string &, FILE *)'
        supportedCmds["history"]        = &Rsh::ashHistory;
                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
4 errors generated.
```

Any suggestions?

---

Fixed with : `map<string, int(Rsh::*)(const string &, FILE*)>   supportedCmds;`
Thank's to @WhiZTiM

Comment: You probably wanted to declare `supportedCmds` as `map<string, int(Rsh::*)(const string &, FILE*)>`

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30605393/assign-a-member-function-to-a-function-pointer but I'm trying to find a target that also shows using a lambda.

Comment: Found a good one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582546/using-generic-stdfunction-objects-with-member-functions-in-one-class

Comment: @WhiZTiM thank's i'm just new with class implementation.

Comment: @GaetanPueo, I am following the same logic as yours. How did you invoke those functions from the map? I tried `(*supportedCmds["cd"])(arg1, arg2)` But it throws the error `Indirection requires pointer operand ('mapped_type' (aka 'void (Rsh::*)(std::__1::basic_string<char> &, ...)') invalid)`

Comment: For those looking for answer to my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18536129/calling-a-member-function-pointer-stored-in-a-std-map