# Vector seemingly changes type dependent on where it's used

Tags: c++, events, vector, pointer-to-member

EDIT: 
The solution:
I tried to create a pointer on a memberfunction and thought the pointer would contain the required informations about the class. It turned out that it didn't.
So Intellisense was absolutely right about the pointer not pointing to an object with the memberfunction but only the memberfunction (or at least that is how I understood it).

In my case I was able to simply use a static member function instead eventhough this function cannot change any memberfunctions without a reference the outer object

---

**Hi** and thanks for taking the time to help me.

I'm currently working on some kind of Event-system. I have a class InputManager which checks if the member-function check is called for events the console-window has reveived and then calls the proper event-handlers which are stored in member-function-pointer-vectors (I will later make it a template).

```
class InputManager
{
private:
    HANDLE cursor;
    DWORD numEventsCaught, consoleMode, i;
    INPUT_RECORD eventBuffer[128];

    std::vector<void (InputForm::*)(KEY_EVENT_RECORD)> keyEventHandlers;
    std::vector<void (InputForm::*)(MOUSE_EVENT_RECORD)> mouseEventHandlers;

public:
    InputManager()
    void addKeyEventHandler(void (InputForm::*e)(KEY_EVENT_RECORD));
    void addMouseEventHandler(void (InputForm::*e)(MOUSE_EVENT_RECORD));

    void check();
};
```

As you can see, the current type of my vector is a **pointer to a member-function** of the InputForm-class with a specific parameter. This is also the type that Visual Studio shows me in the little popup-info.

But as soon as I use that vector inside a member-function, the popup-info shows something different and the it tells me that I need to use a pointer-to type.
**It tells me that the vector has got the type `void (KEY_EVENT_RECORD)` instead of `void (InputForm::*)(KEY_EVENT_RECORD)`.**

I have no idea how that can happen - i mean how can the type of a vector change just by the scope it's used in?

Here is the function where the problem happens (but it also happens in every other function as well):

```
void InputManager::check()
{
    int size;

    if (!ReadConsoleInput(cursor, eventBuffer, 128, &numEventsCaught))
        POST_DEBUG_MESSAGE(-1, "Failed to Read Console Input");

    for (i = 0; i < numEventsCaught; i++)
    {
        switch (eventBuffer[i].EventType)
        {
        case KEY_EVENT:
            size = keyEventHandlers.size();
            for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
            {
                keyEventHandlers[x](eventBuffer[i].Event.KeyEvent); //ERROR ONE
            }

            break;

        case MOUSE_EVENT:
            size = mouseEventHandlers.size();
            for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
            {
                mouseEventHandlers[x](eventBuffer[i].Event.MenuEvent); //ERROR TWO
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Just in case you want to view all the code, here it is (otherwise just ignore it)**

```
InputManager::InputManager()
{
    cursor = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    if (cursor == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        POST_DEBUG_MESSAGE(-1, "Invalid Handle Value, GetStdHandle failed.");

    // Deactivate Quickedit
    consoleMode = ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS;
    if (!SetConsoleMode(cursor, consoleMode))
        POST_DEBUG_MESSAGE(-1, "Failed to set Console Mode (Couldn't deactivate Quickedit)");

    // Activate mouse and window input
    consoleMode = ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT | ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT;
    if (!SetConsoleMode(cursor, consoleMode))
        POST_DEBUG_MESSAGE(-1, "Failed to activate mouse or window inputs");
}

void InputManager::addKeyEventHandler(void (InputForm::*e)(KEY_EVENT_RECORD))
{
    keyEventHandlers.push_back(e);    // Works properly
}

void InputManager::addMouseEventHandler(void (InputForm::*e)(MOUSE_EVENT_RECORD))
{
    mouseEventHandlers.push_back(e);
}
```

**What might be interesting as well** is that even if `keyEventHandlers.push_back(e)` works correctly, it also tells me that e is not member-function-pointer but a usual function pointer -> but the `void (InputForm::*e)(KEY_EVENT_RECORD)` tells me something else...

I really have no clue what's going on here. Do you have an Idea?
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What is this "popup-info" you are talking about? If you are getting an error message, please share it. Is it perhaps telling you that there is no known conversion between `void (KEY_EVENT_RECORD)` and `void (InputForm::*)(KEY_EVENT_RECORD)`?

Comment: You are using your member function pointers as if they were free function pointers. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18536248/7359094) on how to call a member function pointer using `this`. `this` won't be implied when calling a member function pointer like it is for regular member function calls.

Comment: After rereading the question, it seems like you may be hoping to embed the pointer to the instance you want to call the member function on. You can't do this with member function pointers. You'll likely want a vector of [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) instead.

Comment: What i mean with "popup-info": In Visual Studio you get a little info to the object your mouse is hovering over like for example which type it's of.

Comment: After rereading the question, it seems like you may be hoping to embed the pointer to the instance you want to call the member function on. You can't do this with member function pointers. You'll likely want a vector of std::function instead.            Yea i guess thats kinda what i wana do :) thx for the advice

Comment: Where are `addKeyEventHandler()` and `addMouseEventHandler()` called from? Where's that code? And I'm not sure what did you wanted to achieve with `std::vector<void (InputForm::*)(KEY_EVENT_RECORD)>`? Store a pointer to a member function of `InputForm`?

Comment: And what's the exact compiler error, is it so hard to post it here? Your explanation of the error doesn't make any sense. If you wanted to call a member function this function also needs `this` parameter, so `keyEventHandlers[x](eventBuffer[i].Event.KeyEvent);` can't work.

Comment: All the code is [mcve] -- the above is not a [mcve].

Comment: Yea you're right i should explain that a little more. I wanted to be able to add Functions that get called when a certain event happens and i tried to use a vector for storing the functions - or in that case I tried to store pointers to them. Here a member function of InputForm (later of any object if possible)

Comment: I didn't post the exact compile error because of various problems. For one there are currently loads of errors (because I changed the event system which i used in at least 10 others before the change and for another because have to translate them

Comment: Add eventHandler is currently called from my main - sorry that I forgot to post the code of that but I won't be able to post it until tomorrow (I'm on my smartphone right now I didn't think I would get the answers as fast as i got them, I should've waited - I'm not at home anymore)

Comment: You can't store pointer to a member function with one parameter which is not `this`, it's own object's pointer, if that function is not defined as `static`. There's no separate member function for every instance of an object, there's only one member function for all of the object's instances. And every non-static member function receives `this` as an invisible first parameter under the hood. You can achieve this with `std::function` as  François Andrieux pointed out, where first parameter is `this` and others follow the function definition.

Comment: I think I'll try out the advices you already gave me and if that doesn't work I'll send you all the stuff you need. But Thanks for helping me so far :)